# 2015 STI White smoke

Tags: engine, oil, subaru, cooling-system

My 2015 Subaru WRX Sti is emitting white smoke from the exhaust. The smoke smells like burning electronics.  When I pull over and open up the hood, I also see white smoke in the engine bay. The smoke is not overwhelming or anything, but you definitely see it. My engine temps are normal according to the temp gauge, i have no engine check lights, the oil indicator is not lit, I don't notice any type of rough idling or irregularities in the feel of the engine. What could be going on?!

Comment: is your engine oil or your coolent levels dropping?

Comment: White smoke would be Ethylene Glycol - avoid breathing it. Odd that you are getting it in engine bay. Perhaps you have a radiator hose, connector, or pipe leak and your engine is breathing this spray?

Comment: Another thought: Some coolants fluoresce under UV light - get yourself a UV torch and you would easily see coolant leaks (if your have fluorescent coolant).

Comment: Take it back. Warranties are for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds very much like you've blown a head gasket. Even with a new vehicle such as yours, this is not unheard of. There are only two ways you'll get white smoke that I'm aware of, those being a blown head gasket or it sucking up automatic transmission fluid. A head gasket is much more common. I'm sure this thing is still under warranty, so get it down to the dealership and have them fix it.

**EDIT:** I guess you could also have a leak in the cooling system somewhere it mates up with the intake tract ... this would be better than a blown head gasket, but is still not good.

Comment: I'd suspect the turbo before the headgasket.

Comment: Most likely seals on the shaft in the turbo, yes.